# Firefox add-on access all the console log information

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, console.log

I am developing an add-on in Firefox. As a part of the add-on, I am opening a tab with a new page, and once the page is completely loaded, I would like access the web console log information (css/javascript errors.....

How do I access all the console log information once the page is loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get the innerID of the window that you want to obtain messages from.

With the sdk you can get this with `var innerID = require("sdk/window/utils").getInnerId(require("sdk/view/core").viewFor(require("sdk/windows").activeWindow))`

or more cleanly:

```
var utils = require("sdk/window/utils");
var viewFor = require("sdk/view/core").viewFor;
var windows = require("sdk/windows");


var innerID = utils.getInnerId(viewFor(windows.activeWindow));
```

Then you want to observe console notifications for that window:

```
var system = require("sdk/system/events");

system.on('console-api-log-event', onMessage);

function onMessage(subject) {
  subject = subject.wrappedJSObject;

  if (subject.innerID != innerID) {
    return null; //ignore this console log, because it is for a window/thing that I don't care about
  }

  if (subject.level != "log") {
    return null; // ignore anything but console.log, like: console.info, console.error, console.debug, etc.
  }

  var message = subject.arguments[0]; // first string argument to console.log()
  // do something with the console.log("") message
}
```

Comment: That should work for the log our add-on write using console.log.
However, we need to read the console output which is written by not us.
For example, in case of Javascript error on the page, you would see something like

JavaScript error: file:///index.html, line 6: xxx is not defined

Is there any way to get this kind of message from console?